# Namespace/subdomain in Gitlab not working

Tags: gitlab, subdomain, gitlab-ce

I am new on Gitlab. In several tutorials, I see domains like `myname.gitlab.io` or `myname.gitlab.com` as well `gitlab.com/myname`. But I only call `gitlab.com/myname`, the others throw a 404 error.

**Do I have to activate the subdomains somehow?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

Just *rename your project* to `namespace.gitlab.io`, where namespace is
your username or groupname. This can be done by navigating to your
project's Settings.

https://gitlab.com/pages/hugo#gitlab-user-or-group-pages